# using GCD but my app is still freezing when loading images from server

Tags: ios, objective-c, sql-server, multithreading

I'm essentially loading images from the server every time a user taps the refresh button. However, this loading mechanism freezes the main thread, so I decided to try and use GCD to load the images in a different thread. I've looked at tutorials, and it seems that I'm setting it up right, but I'm still encountering the same issue.

My code:

```
-(IBAction)refreshButton:(id)sender{

    dispatch_queue_t myQueue = dispatch_queue_create("My Queue",NULL);

    dispatch_async(myQueue, ^{
        [[API sharedInstance] commandWithParams:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                 @"stream",@"command",@"0",@"IdImage",_contentFilter,@"contentFilter",
                                                 nil]
                                   onCompletion:^(NSDictionary *json){
                                       NSMutableArray *tempArray = [json objectForKey:@"result"];
                                       NSMutableArray *tempDataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[_imagesTemporaryHolder count]];
                                       NSLog(@"loaded temporary image holder");
                                       for (int i=0;i<[_images count];i++) {
                                           NSLog(@" populating _imagesData");
                                           NSString *imageID = [[tempArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"IdImage"];
                                           NSString *imageURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://swiphtapp.com/Swipht/upload/%@.jpg",imageID];
                                           NSData *tempImageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:imageURL]];
                                           [tempDataArray insertObject:tempImageData atIndex:i];
                                        }


                                   }];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // Update the UI

        });
    });

}
```

Could it be that I need to go to the API class and change something there? I'm using **AFNNETWORKING** by the way.

Thank you so much for the help!

**UPDATE 1**:

It looks like the API's "onCompletion" block is what's causing the problem...I did the NSLog(isMainThread) check in it, and it returns YES meaning that it's running in the main thread although it shouldn't be as I've encapsulated it in the GCD. Thoughts on how to solve this?

**ANSWERED THANKS TO AWESOME PEOPLE**

@eric

The completion block of the API call is meant to be performed on the main thread, because it's where you would normally update the views based on the data received. Try placing your GCD stuff INSIDE the completion block instead of encapsulating the whole thing in it. It's taking so long on the main thread because you are getting the NSData from the url returned from your original API call, which can take a long time (relatively speaking)

Basically the GCD needed to be in the API call's completion block.

Thanks again!

Comment: AFNetworking already does the api calls in the background, so I assume you are locking the main thread up somewhere else?

Comment: @eric I haven't added any other server side api than the ones included in the AFNetworking package.

Comment: Have you used xCodes Instruments yet? I would try digging around the time profiler to see what's taking up the CPU time

Comment: I haven't used it before...is my code in the block correct though?

Comment: It looks right to me. You should be able to do all the AFNetworking calls without using GCD, and once you have all the data start updating your images. Also you may want to try using AFNetworking's UIImageView Category. You can supply a UIImageView with a url, and AFNetworking takes care of downloading the image in the background and loading it into the UIImageView. NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString: imageURL];
[YourImageView setImageWithURL:url placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder"]];

Comment: Are you certain that the onCompletion block isn't being called on the main thread? Add something like NSLog(@"isMainThread? %@", [NSThread isMainThread] ? @"YES" : @"NO"); to your completion handler.  It may be that is where your bottleneck is.

Comment: BTW GCD does *not* increase the performance of an application just by magically using it.  You have to still be prudent about when and what you dispatch.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I will try this stuff and let you know!

Comment: @eric  i dont think the issue is with loading the images into the UIImageView's because as you see in the code, I don't even apply the data into the image view's. I'm just loading the data into an array, and that causes the app to freeze.

Comment: @NicholasHart I ran that NSLog and I got NO, so it's not being run in the main thread. Not sure exactly what else to do/how to proceed from here.

Comment: It looks like the API's "onCompletion" block is what's causing the problem...I did the NSLog(isMainThread) check in it, and it returns YES meaning that it's running in the main thread although it shouldn't be as I've encapsulated it in the GCD. Thoughts on how to solve this?

Comment: The completion block of the API call is meant to be performed on the main thread, because it's where you would normally update the views based on the data received. Try placing your GCD stuff INSIDE the completion block instead of encapsulating the whole thing in it. It's taking so long on the main thread because you are getting the NSData from the url returned from your original API call, which can take a long time (relatively speaking)

Comment: What Eric said is very important to understand.  Just because you used dispatch_async to invoke your code on a different queue does not mean that a block of code you pass to another API is going to run on that same queue.  The caller who receives that block could (and in this case does) use GCD to invoke the block on a different dispatch queue (in this case, the main queue).

Comment: Also, if you just want to run on a background queue there's no need to create your own queue.  Just use dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0) to get the default background queue.

Comment: @RoyH Cool glad we could help. I put a solution below, if that one works mark it as correct so you can help people in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is the answer we came to in the comments under the initial post:

```
-(IBAction)refreshButton:(id)sender
{
    [[API sharedInstance] commandWithParams:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                             @"stream",@"command",@"0",@"IdImage",_contentFilter,@"contentFilter",
                                             nil]
                               onCompletion:^(NSDictionary *json){

                                   dispatch_queue_t myQueue = dispatch_queue_create("My Queue",NULL);

                                   dispatch_async(myQueue, ^{
                                       NSMutableArray *tempArray = [json objectForKey:@"result"];
                                       NSMutableArray *tempDataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[_imagesTemporaryHolder count]];
                                       NSLog(@"loaded temporary image holder");
                                       for (int i=0;i<[_images count];i++) {
                                           NSLog(@" populating _imagesData");
                                           NSString *imageID = [[tempArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"IdImage"];
                                           NSString *imageURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://swiphtapp.com/Swipht/upload/%@.jpg",imageID];
                                           NSData *tempImageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:imageURL]];
                                           [tempDataArray insertObject:tempImageData atIndex:i];
                                        }
                                       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                           // Update the UI

                                       });
                                   });
                               }];
}
```